# SDWebImage SwiftUI Animated GIF not looping?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, animated-gif, sdwebimage

Basically certain gifs just aren't looping under this framework. It will run once then never again on appear. This happens on both simulator and previews. Oddly enough **this problem only occurs with specific GIFs.** And I have yet to find the reason why... I'll link those below:

Here's example code:

```
AnimatedImage(name: "handGesture.gif")
       .resizable()
       .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
       .frame(width: 60)
```

(I've tried fiddling with all the playback settings—nothing seems to fix it)

All help is highly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Not all gif loop. It's a setting inside them. See https://help.behance.net/hc/en-us/articles/115004491127-FAQ-How-do-I-set-my-GIF-to-play-on-loop-

Comment: You can also look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF for "Unsigned number of repetitions" or "This block, placed immediately before the sequence of animation frames, specifies the number of times the sequence of frames should be played (1 to 65535 times) or that it should repeat continuously (zero indicates loop forever)" part.

Comment: I opened the hand gif into Safari.app and it played only once. I opened it in XCode, and it plays continously, that's just how Xcode show them, but in fact it shouldn't loop.